# A textbook question regarding arrangements and permutations of 5 cows and 2 calves in seven stalls

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Can I please get some help in the following question:

Five cows and one set of twin calves can be housed separately in a row of seven stalls in $7P7 =5040$.  Find in how many of these arrangements:

(a) the two calves are not in adjacent stalls

(b) the two calves and their mother, who is one of the 5 cows, are in adjacent stalls

(c) each calf is in a stall adjacent to its mother

My working:

a) $5040-1440=3600$. I considered the calf as a single entity to calculate the arrangements where they were adjacent $6P6 \cdot 2P2$, then subtracted from total to get the arrangements where they were not adjacent.

b) I did $5P1$ to get the possible mother from the five cows, then $5P1 \cdot 3P3$ to permute the mother and the two calves, finally, I considered the mother and two calf to be a single unit and permuted them with the remaining 4 cows. $5P1 \cdot 3P3 \cdot 5P5 = 3600$.

c) I think this part implies that each calf has a different mother ? So I took $5P1$ for the first mother and $4P1$ for the second mother and then permuted the five objects. $5P1 \cdot 4P1 \cdot 2P2 \cdot 2P2 \cdot 5P5=9600$.

My answer to part a is correct but the answers to parts b and c are $720$ and $240$, respectively.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In how many ways can five cows and two calves be housed in separate stalls in a row of seven stalls if the two calves and their mother, who is one of the five cows, are in adjacent stalls?

The mother of the two calves is a particular cow.  We do not need to select her, which is why your answer is five times the stated answer.

Treat the mother and her two calves as a unit.  Then we have five objects to arrange, the block containing the mother and her two calves and the other four cows.  The five objects can be arranged in $5!$ ways.  The mother and her two calves can be arranged within their block in $3!$ ways.  Hence, there are $5!3!$ arrangements in which the two calves and their mother are in adjacent stalls.

> In how many ways can five cows and two calves be housed in separate stalls in a row of seven stalls if each calf is in a stall adjacent to its mother?

The problem clearly states that the two calves have the same mother. Again, the mother is a particular cow, so we do not need to choose the mother.

As above, treat the mother and her calves as a unit.  Then we have five objects to arrange, the block containing the mother and her two calves and the other four cows.  The five objects can be arranged in $5!$ ways.  Since each calf is adjacent to its mother, the mother cow must be in the middle stall of the three adjacent stalls containing the mother and her two calves.  The two calves can be arranged next to the mother in $2!$ ways.  Hence, there are $5!2!$ arrangements in which each calf is adjacent to its mother.

Comment: Oh ok, so a particular cow is the mother and part c is linked to part b as in both the calves have the same mother, thank you

Comment: can you please look at : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4801451/distributing-balls-into-bins-with-some-conditions

Answer (score -1):

Arrangements where

1. The two calves are in adjacent stalls = $^4P_4 \times ^2P_2 = 4! \times 2 = 48$
2. The two calves are adjacent to their mother: $^3P_3 \times ^3P_3 = 3! \times 3! = 36$
3. Each calf is adjacent to its mother: $^3P_3 \times \times 2! = 6 \times 2 = 12$

Comment: All three of your answers are incorrect.

Comment: How so? Explain ... please. They are true for 3 cows and 2 calves, oui? 

Comment: The question states that there are *five* cows and two calves.